# Why does adding a groups option to the symfony serializer remove all properties?

Tags: php, symfony

User Object:

```
/**
 * User
 */
class User implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $userName;
```

Serializer.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    Attributes:
        id:
            groups: ['user', 'challenge', 'submission']
        firstName:
            groups: ['user', 'challenge', 'submission']
        lastName:
            groups: ['user', 'challenge', 'submission']
        userName:
            groups: ['challenge', 'submission']
```

Controller

```
public function usersAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    /** @var User[] $user */
    $users = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
        ->findAll();

    if (empty($users)) {
        return new JsonResponse(['message' => 'There are no users'], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    $json = $this->get('serializer')->serialize(
        $users,
        'json',
        ['groups' => ['user']]
    );

    return new Response($json, Response::HTTP_OK, [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ]);
}
```

The issue that I am having is that If I add the 'user' value to the serializer the outputted $json is just an array of empty arrays, If I remove it I get the json returned, but it will include the userName value that I am trying to exclude.  I am using the serializer service that comes with Symfony 2.8.  Am I supposed to configure it with the $classMetaDataFactory?  Additionally, I am trying not to use annotations, I am trying to use YAML so the entities don't become too cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your file name for the serializer configuration is incorrect.

> In addition to the @Groups annotation, the Serializer component also supports Yaml or XML files. These files are automatically loaded when being stored in one of the following locations:
>
> The serialization.yml or serialization.xml file in the Resources/config/ directory of a bundle;
> All *.yml and *.xml files in the Resources/config/serialization/ directory of a bundle.

Also please confirm you have set the serializer to be enabled and not with annotations

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    # ...
    serializer: { enabled: true }
```